# How to compare two records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables containing a new and an old `dataset`. I want to see if something happened in the individual records.

**OLD TABLE:**

```
ROW ID  FIELD_A FIELD_B FIELD_C
1   101 A       B       C
2   102 AA      BB      CC
3   103 AAA     BBB     CCC
```

**NEW TABLE:**

```
ROW ID  FIELD_A FIELD_B FIELD_C
711 101 A       B       C
712 102 AAXXXXX BB      CC
713 103 AAA     BBB     CCC
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
ROW ID  FIELD_A FIELD_B FIELD_C
712 102 AAXXXXX BB      CC
```

I want to be able to identify the difference in the record with `id =102`. Note, that my real life record is much bigger with MANY columns that need to be compared. What is the best way to do this comparison?

Comment: please post your expected output

Comment: Many fields means many columns right?

Comment: I assume you should get familiar with queries that use EXCEPT and INTERSECT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: @techdo: Yes, many columns

Comment: @FathahRehmanP, will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from NewTable
except
select * from OldTable
```

[Ways to compare and find differences for SQL Server tables and data](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/)

Its a way, if its the best one I am not sure.

Comment: This was my first thought, too, but I believe the OP wants to identify the actual differences.  For a particular pair of records, this will only tell you whether they are different.

Comment: i think the answer must be more complicated, since except changes on any table, deletes, and inserts can happen too!
so the result must contain an extra column that shows us deleted, inserted or updated rows !

Comment: `select "inserted", * from (select * from NewTable except select * from OldTable) union select "deleted", * from (select * from OldTable except select * from NewTable)`, but this does not identify the modifications; for those, you'll need a `join`, as @SMS is suggesting.

Comment: I think OP was looking for performance differences between all these aproaches. because given set is fairly large.

Comment: @Morten, then you should "accept" this answer.  (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get only matching rows use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM newtable INTERSECT SELECT * FROM oldtable
```

If yuo want to get only different record use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM newtable EXCEPT SELECT * FROM oldtable
```

Answer (score 0):

By using query, below will give the records from new table if columns values does not match with old table. You need to add all the columns in the query

```
SELECT N.FIELD_A, N.FIELD_B, N.Field_C FROM NewTable N
LEFT JOIN OldTable O ON 
    O.FIELD_A = N.FIELD_A AND O.FIELD_B = N.FIELD_B AND O.FIELD_C = N.FIELD_C
WHERE O.FIELD_A IS NULL
```

If you have more columns in the table, can you try adding a column like ModifiedDate in both tables. Update the datetime whenever changes are made to the table. By this way you dont need to compare all the columns, only just compare the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the tables have identical structures, this query will output a query for each column that will give you an A/B comparison of the differences:

```
SELECT 'SELECT a.' + COLUMN_NAME +
       '     , b.' + COLUMN_NAME +
       '  FROM old_table a' + 
       '     , new_table b ' +
       ' WHERE a.id = b.id ' +
       '   AND a.' + COLUMN_NAME + 
       '    <> b.' + COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'old_table'
   AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'id'
```

You can copy the output from this into a new query window and run it.

If all you care about *whether* there is a difference, the `EXCEPT`-based answer is much simpler and faster.  This will tell you *what* the actual differences are.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from oldtable a inner join newtable b on a.id=b.id
where a.fielda<> b.fielda or a.fieldb<>b.fieldb or  a.fieldc<> b.fieldc
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the record that has changed in your new table just use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM newtable EXCEPT SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```

If you are sure of the columns which would be having changes, you could specify those columns in the `SELECT` and make the query more efficient.